# Oracle JSON Query with hyphen-key

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c, json-value

I have an Oracle database in version 12.1.0.2.0 and JSON field that I want to query.

This query works:

```
select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$."de"') from DUAL
```

This query returns the error **ORA-40442**.

```
select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$."-"') from DUAL
```

Queries to the hyphen are no problem with MySQL and MSSQL.

I can't change the JSON-string.

How can I still query for the hyphen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use unicode representation:

```
select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$."\u002d"') from DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both**

`select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$."de"') from DUAL`

*and*

`select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$."-"') from DUAL`

**works**

**unless** `JSON-path-expression` containing non-alphanumeric character which is unquoted such as :

`select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$.-') from DUAL`

*or*

`select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$.d-e') from DUAL`

**doesn't work** and return the error `ORA-40442`

**But**

`select JSON_VALUE('{"-": "hello", "de":"hallo"}','$.de') from DUAL`

works without problem, even it's unquoted.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7bef27a9581662c6f4e4849ca22c8bfe)</kbd>